# Javascript for validating select box

Tags: php, javascript

```
<select name="fruits">
   <option value="apple">Apple</option>
   <option value="orange">Orange</option>
   <option value="pears">Pears</option>
</select>

/* fruits stored in the database */
<?php  $items as $each_fruit) {
   $fruit_count++;
   $a[]=$each_fruit->fruit_name;
?>
```

The selected values are already stored in the database. I don't want to allow to add the fruit again....

How can I check that using javascript?

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use Javascript?

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish here.  Are you trying to prevent the system from adding multiple identical entries to the list as it renders?  Are you trying to prevent users from modifying the list in the browser?  Please clarify.  One point of advice though, if you're intending to use JavaScript to validate input then you'll still want to re-validate in PHP.  Never trust any data coming from the client.

Comment: @David I am adding the apple for the first time and the value is stored in the database.I shouldn't let the user to add apple the next time.

Comment: @Truth how can I do in php? please advise.

Comment: Never trust clients.... Only validate with JavaScript for user-feedback; like highlighting required fields or mismatched emails, etc

Comment: @Merryba: The fact that you can only think of one way to do this does not mean that you should ask for *that* solution. Ask for *a* solution to begin with, and see what people answer.

Comment: @Merryba: If am not wrong, are you trying to insert all the unique values (get from database) to the select dropdown?

Comment: @SivaCharan for each person I get their favourite fruit and I add them to the database,this is not a mulitple selectbox. So if they selected apple for the first time,it is saved to the database.If Apple is selected the next time,then we should not allow apple to be saved.

Comment: So what does JS have to do about it? Make you're query in php and check whether the fruit is already in the DB.

Comment: <script language="JavaScript">
var fruits = new Array("<?php $a;?>"); I tried this.But I'm getting error. How to pass php array to javascript.SO that I can validate the selected value in Javascript.

Comment: I got the answer <script type="text/javascript">
var somejsarray = <?php echo json_encode($a) ?>;
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php  $items as $each_fruit) {
   $fruit_count++;
   $a[]=$each_fruit->fruit_name;
?>
```

**$selectedValue** - Assign the user selected value to this variable

```
if (!in_array($selectedValue, $a)) {
    // Do your stuff
```